# How make Tabs public on Force.com Sites

Tags: force.com-sites, tab, community

Actually I'm not sure if this is possible or not.
I had setup a Community (new SF portal approach) and now I would like to share some of the Community tabs with my Force.com site. Btw, it is a "Force.com Community"

I found on the Sites documentation that this is possible using Apps:

> Control the visibility of custom apps. If you want to expose a custom
>   app and its associated tabs to public users, make only that app
>   visible and make it the default to avoid exposing other pages. If any
>   of your site pages use standard Salesforce headers, other visible
>   applications may be seen by public users.

http://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_public_access_settings.htm

I tried to do this clicking on my site label and then on Public Access Settings, as a result I land on a profile called Customer Support Profile. Then on Apps section I click on Assigned Apps and the only listed App is Platform.

So I thought I had to assign the public site profile (Customer Support Profile) to the Plataform app.
I went to Create > Apps, clicked on Platform, then Edit but Customer Support Profile is not listed !

I would appreciate advice here.
Thanks !

Comment: Is this the same question with http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/605/add-tabs-in-public-sites ?

Answer (score 2):

What you can actually expose is limited by the type of licenses you have. As I understand it, even the new salesforce communities require a license; albeit a less expensive one.

Any app you create has to be accessed through a customer portal. With communities being new, I don't believe all of the documentation has completely caught up with them, but licensing is still an issue that has to be addressed before they can be implemented.

We're in the midst of building a site based on the High Volume Customer Portal license that will transition to Communities licenses once the existing HVCP licenses expire. In any case, it's the profile for the license you'll be using that needs to have the tabs enabled.